# is it dangerous to put the client_secret on the client side?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I want to create an authentication system with laravel  , passport and vue js . Which is the best choice

1 - laravel

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
}
```

1 - vuejs

```
    axios.post('/login', {
                    'username': 'xxxxxx',
                    'password':'xxxxxxxxx'
                })
                    .then(response => {
                 //login
                    }).catch(error => {
                   //error
                })
```

2-vuejs

```
    axios.post('/oauth/token', {
                    'username': 'xxxxxx',
                    'password':'xxxxxxxxx',
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                     'client_id' => 'client-id',
                     'client_secret' => 'client-secret',

                })
                    .then(response => {
                 //login
                    }).catch(error => {
                   //error
                })
```

In Solution 2, is it dangerous to put the client_secret on the client side?

Comment: Is the passport app hosted on the same domain as your vuejs app?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.  Keep it in a .env file and make sure to put it in your .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Solution 1. In Solution 2 everyone can read the client_secret and pretend to be the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest option 3: [using passports built in JS authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

You authenticate using the standard auth flow that ships with Laravel. Then add the `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class` middleware on the routes that serve VueJS. Make sure your axios is configured to include the CSRF token by default. If you use the app.js that ships with laravel then this is already done for you. You can then make your axios requests as usual. (making sure to include the CSRF token. Th.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use solution 1. It protects your OAuth service keeping it hidden and not reacheable. In addition you should implement a mechanism to refresh the tokens.